# Copy-paste based on date

Tags: excel, vba

Ultra Newb here with Excel VBA. The sheets data comes from a userform which the user enters info which includes a use by date which goes into column C.
I have an ActiveX button on sheet1, which i would like to run like a search of all the dates in column C previous to today's date and anything in 7 days time to be cut and pasted to sheet 3.

I apologize in advance if this is not specific enough.
I would also appreciate any and all input on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the code that did what I was after. Here it is:

```
Private Sub cmd2_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range, sh2 As Worksheet, lr2 As Long
Set sh = Sheets(1) 'Edit sheet name
Set sh2 = Sheets(3) 'Edit Sheet name
lr = sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh.Range("C2:C" & lr)
For Each c In rng
If DateValue(c.Value) <= DateValue(Date) Then
lr2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
c.EntireRow.Copy sh2.Range("A" & lr2)
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit to broad to be meaningfully answered. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

But for what you are describing there are a lot of resources you can use:

- [Userforms](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html)
- [Getting Started with VBA in Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737.aspx)
- [Macros, Worksheets, Loop, Arrays ... (a bit of everything)](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html)

If you get stuck or there's anything more specific we can answer just come back and we'll answer it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've revised my question a little. Does this help clear things up at all?